# Windows 8 BSOD: PAGE_FAULT in raspptp.sys

Tags: windows-8, bsod

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I resolve BSOD: PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA?](https://superuser.com/questions/241495/how-do-i-resolve-bsod-page-fault-in-nonpaged-area)

.

Any ideas on this BSOD?  What extra helpful info can I provide?

[image]
.

Answer (score 0):

This is a driver builtin to Windows for the "Peer to Peer Tunneling Protocol". You can encounter BSOD errors if you are trying to use two different VPN solutions at the same time, or if a virus has masqueraded itself as raspptp.sys (which is normally non-malicious on a default Windows install).

Since this is a kernel crash, it could be due to any one of your kernel modules interfering with raspptp, or (less likely) an issue with raspptp itself.